# Как подключить SSL Apache + Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl, httpd

Столкнулся с проблемой подключения SSL Apache + Node.JS, может у кого есть пример конфига, прилагаю ниже www.js и conf для apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName moy-sait.com
ServerAlias www.moy-sait.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moy-sait/public

DirectoryIndex index.hbs

<Directory "/var/www/html/moy-sait">
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

ProxyRequests off
<Location />
#ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>

ErrorLog logs/moy-sait.error.log
CustomLog logs/moy-sait.requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName moy-sait.com
ServerAlias www.moy-sait.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moy-sait/public

DirectoryIndex index.hbs

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/moy-sait.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/moy-sait.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/moy-sait.ca"
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH

<Directory "/var/www/html/moy-sait">
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

ProxyRequests off
<Location />
#ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass http://localhost:4000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4000/
</Location>

ErrorLog logs/moy-sait.error.log
CustomLog logs/moy-sait.requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var app_1 = require("./app");
var app_2 = require("./app");
var http = require("http");


/*For SSL Connection*/

var express = require("express");
var app_2 = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var key = fs.readFileSync("/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/moy-sait.key");
var cert = fs.readFileSync( "/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/moy-sait.crt" );
var ca = fs.readFileSync( "/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/moy-sait.ca" );

var options = {
 key: key,
 cert: cert,
 ca: ca
};

var https = require("https");
https.createServer(options, app_2.app).listen(4000);

/**/

var Server = /** @class */ (function () {
function Server() {
    this.port = this.normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
    app_1.app.set('port', this.port);
    this.server = http.createServer(app_1.app);
    this.server.listen(this.port);
    this.server.on('error', this.onError);
}
Server.prototype.normalizePort = function (val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);
    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }
    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }
    return false;
};
Server.prototype.onError = function (error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }
    var bind = typeof this.port === 'string'
        ? 'Pipe ' + this.port
        : 'Port ' + this.port;
    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
};
return Server;
}());
var kek = new Server();
```

---

Вопрос решен! Всем спасибо, проблема была в конфиге www.js и конфиге apache

Comment: А проблема то в чём?

Comment: На вскидку в конфиге apache не хватает ProxyEngine On для 80 порта и SSLProxyEngine On для 443. И 443 вроде должен проксироваться на 'https:// localhost:4000'.

Comment: @Устьянцев Борис  сейчас тестану с вашими замечаниями

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис Не вышло, если обращаться к 
https://moy-sait.com:4000/ - то ожидание и все, если к 
https://moy-sait.com - то такая ошибка 


Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Comment: Ну судя по всему apache работает и проксирует, а node не отдаёт результат на 4000 порту.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис Вот я и не могу понять почему (

Comment: Можно посмотреть логи node. Можно попробовать curl --verbose https:// localhost:4000.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис  * Could not resolve host: https; Unknown error
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: https; Unknown error
* About to connect() to localhost port 4000 (#1)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 4000 (#1)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:4000
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #1 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: А точно пробел перед localhost:4000 убрали?

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис Да, и порт он подымает, и 80 порт сайт работает, а 443 нет

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис  

   `var https = require('https');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/__english-club_tv.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync( "/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/__english-club_tv.crt" ),
    ca: fs.readFileSync( "/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/__english-club_tv.ca" )
    };
 
    http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
    https.createServer(options, app).listen(4443);`

Когда делаю тест приложение то все работает

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис А зачем вам проксировать HTTPS до node.js? Это тройная работа - расшифровать SSL на апаче, зашифровать для проксирования, расшифровать на node.js. Проксируйте HTTP!